# Insufficient privileges when adding fields in package (changeset)

Tags: package, change-set, unmanaged-package

I am getting an "insufficient privileges" error when adding fields (yes, just fields) to a package I'm building, despite the fact I'm system administrator using a DE (I am creating a brand new application).

I found other "insufficient privileges" instances when adding other stuff to the changeset...

I've been to the system administrator profile and found nothing related to changeset permissions (nor the object settings for that matter).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are any of the fields or components you're attempting to add to the changeset related to a managed package you have installed? I assume you're getting these errors when you attempt to validate or deploy. Sometimes these error messages are red herrings and can be resolved because there is something else that is off in the changeset that needs to be corrected.

Comment: 1. No, these fields (and there's even a custom report type in it) are all unmanaged; 2. The error appears when adding them to the change set (actually, it's a package).

Answer (score 0):

Well it was the "change set helper" plugin. Sorry.

Comment: Which plugin is that?  A Chrome extension?  Can you edit your answer to include that detail?  Thanks.

Comment: It's ORGanizer Change Set Helper Plugin. Sorry I didn't mention it.